# Middleware Laravel y Vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Integré Laravel y Vue todo lo que está en vue js comienza con la ruta http://localhost:8000/#/ se agrega el /#/, estoy teniendo problemas para que me reconozca los middleware de laravel en vue, utilizo:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/profile', [
        'as' => 'dos.vers',
        'uses' => 'ThumbnailController@view',
    ]);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para eliminar el `#` de las rutas, agrega `mode: 'history'`:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

Más información: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html